# Semantic mediawiki: Number of (unlimited) results for query to ask api

Tags: mediawiki-api

I'd like to get a number of results, which are available for a query from the semantic mediawiki. Ask API, where the number of results is greater than the query limit. Adding `|format%3Dcount` to the query parameter throws this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   ApiSMWQuery::addQueryResult() must be an instance of SMWQueryResult,
>   string given, called in
>   /Users/andru/Development/practicalplants/public/w/extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/includes/api/ApiAsk.php
>   on line 32 and defined in
>   /Users/andru/Development/practicalplants/public/w/extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/includes/api/ApiSMWQuery.php
>   on line 51

from (eg.) `/w/api?action=ask&query=[[Property::+]]|limit%3D5|format%3Dcount`

Does anyone know of an alternate route for this via the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formats like “count” are not covered by the SMW API, as far as I know (see [bug 46458](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46458)), but writing an extension that serves that kind of data from the API would probably not be to hard.

If the number does not need to be very exact, you could also set a property containing the count from an inline query, like `{{#set:Number of results={{#ask:[[Property::+]]|format=count}}}}`. That value would however only be updated when the page is saved.